# Mysterious Error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to develop a game, and for some strange reason, my code doesn't work (Haven't we all been there?) My code works fine, until I add the code (Below the slashes), and it just stops working. I have been on it for hours. Am I doing something wrong? How can I fix? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
        if(platformCoords[i][j] == 0)
        {
            tmp++;
        }
    }

    if(tmp > 11)
    {
        XX++;
    }
    else
    {
        i = 99;
        j = 99;
    }
    tmp = 0;
}
//This is the evilness which has plagued me//   
for(var k = 12; k > -1; k--)
{
    for(var l = 0; l < 12; l++)
    {
        if(platformCoords[k][l] == 0)
        {
            tmp++;
        }
    }

    if(tmp > 11)
    {
        XY--;
    }
    else
    {
        k = -2;
        l = 99;
    }
    tmp = 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting `k` too high. `platformCoords` apparently has entries 0 through 11 (inclusive), based on your first (functioning) loop. But the second loop, which you said fails, starts with `k = 12`. It should start with `k = 11`.

In both cases (the first and second loops), rather than magic numbers in the code (11, 12), you should be using `platformCoords.length` for less brittle code. So:

```
for(var i = 0; i < platformCoords.length; i++)
```

and

```
for(var k = platformCoords.length - 1; k > -1; k--)
```

and so on

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know how I missed such a silly mistake costing me hours. Thank you also for teaching me a new useful method!